# Layout: Appbar is not visible correctly

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, layout, android-viewpager

[image]

In this image toolbar is not working correctly in Marshmallow. I have given `android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"` height in toolbar which is working correctly in below Marshmallow devices. My device resolution is 1080x1920 xxhdpi and OS is Marshmallow.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/dp_28"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_more_horiz"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_header_left"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/img_close"
                android:gravity="center">

                <com.happening.customview.LatoBlackTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title_fr_no"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dp_5"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/dp_5"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_24" />

                <com.happening.customview.LatoBlackTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title_fix"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv_title_fr_no"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_title_fr_no"
                    android:text="@string/fix_six"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_16" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_close"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:padding="@dimen/dp_15"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
                android:tint="@color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my activity layout in which I have used pager for n no of fragments, and for my fragment item view is below.

I have called fragments in view pager and each fragment also has one viewopager for image slide show.

Comment: Are you using full screen (SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)?